# DEVPI Server - "devpi login" returns 404

Tags: devpi

I am running devpi behind haproxy and not able to login.
devpi login username returns 404.

```
GET https://devpi.example.com/+login 
404 Not Found: <!doctype html>
<snip>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The following resource could not be found:</p>
        <p>predicate mismatch for view PyPIView (request_method = POST)</p>
    </div>
```

Passed in a --debug flag for starting the server, but it is just mimimal

```
2018-09-13 17:52:07,157 INFO  [req663] GET /+login
2018-09-13 17:52:07,157 DEBUG [req663] [Rtx72] in-transaction 72
2018-09-13 17:52:07,159 DEBUG [req663] [Rtx72] closing transaction at 72
2018-09-13 17:52:07,159 DEBUG [req663] 404 0.003s serial=72 length=5458 type=text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried passing in values for `--outside-url` which doesn't help.
Login is successful if I port forward to localhost and try with localhost:.

Using devpi-server-4.7.1 & devpi-web-3.4.0.

Has anyone seen this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Fix the login URL in `.devpi/client/current.json` so that there is no url *redirection by the proxy.

Comment: I've got the same issue, and I don't understand your solution. What URL did you use in your client config, and why is the client config wrong?

Comment: See: cat ~/.devpi/client/current.json

Also, look at ----clientdir parameter.